# Send Json to nodejs server

Tags: ajax, json, node.js, jquery, zepto

I develop an app with a REST nodejs server and a JavaScript / Zepto client.

I'm trying to send an json string from my client to my server

here is the client code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/request',
    data: JSON.stringify({test : "test"}),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    complete: callback,
    processData : false,
    success : function(){
        console.log("toto");
    },
    error : function(){
        console.log("erreur")
    }
});
```

And my node code :

```
app.post('/request', request.request);

// request.js
exports.request = function(req, res){
    console.log(req.body);
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.send("OK");
}
```

But my node console print this: `{{test : "test"} : ""}`

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From reading the [zepto documentation](http://zeptojs.com/#%24.param) I would suggest you let zepto handling the encoding of the data.

Try:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/request',
    data: {
        test: "test"
    },
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    ....
});
```